# Problem with IsIndeterminate while trying to put together a ProgressBar XAML template

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, animation, progress-bar

I´m creating a XAML template for the WPF `ProgressBar`. The following XAML code works fine if `IsIndeterminate` is set to `False`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultProgressBarTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SolidBorderBrush" Color="#767676" />
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="IndicatorBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Color="#BCCF64" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="#E1FF77" Offset="0.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Grid MinHeight="14">
        <Border Name="PART_Track" CornerRadius="9" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
        <Border Name="PART_Indicator" CornerRadius="9" Background="{StaticResource IndicatorBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SolidBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ProgressBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DefaultProgressBarTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

The indicator border fills up the `ProgressBar` from min to max. But if I set `IsIndeterminate` to `True` the indicator border fills up the entire `ProgressBar` (like it is set to max) and nothing is animated at all. Nothing I tried did change this behaviour of the `ProgressBar`.
What do I have to do to have an `IsIndeterminate` animation similar to the one in the standard WPF `ProgressBar`?

Thanks in advance

banzai

Comment: I'm a little confused, what exactly do you want your indicator border to do when IsIndeterminate is true?

Comment: The animation should run from left to right and back and so on like it is common in Windows ProgressBars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProgressBar` is designed to show the entire indicator when `IsIndeterminate="true"`.  WPF's built in `ProgressBar` styles actually replace the indicator color with an animated brush whenever `IsIndeterminate="true"` to cause the effect you are observing.  You could do the same.  Just use a property trigger on `IsIndeterminate="true"` and set the brush to a brush whose colors you are animating.  Another option would be to create a separate animation triggered by `IsIndeterminate="true"` if you wanted a different effect.

You can look at the built-in styles by using the NET Reflector tool along with its BamlViewer add-in.  The original source files are also copied onto your hard disk when Expression Blend is installed, even the evaluation version, so installing Expression Blend is another way to see the XAML for the built-in styles.  Just look in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Expression\Blend 2\SystemThemes` directory.

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm glad it worked for you.  Did you know you can mark an answer as correct, which tells others it is correct, and also gives the answerer 15 reputation points?