# Silverlight Facebook A-Like Busy Indicator

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, user-interface

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a busy indicator with the following style: [image]

The default busy indicator I don't like so I wanted to customize it and have it appear like the above? But I don't think I can use 'gif' images in silverlight. Anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[In this post you can see how a progress bar can be templated](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/)

It might be easiest to do this in Blend instead of typing it in XAML.

Have a look at this question too: [Problem with IsIndeterminate while trying to put together a ProgressBar XAML template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049444/problem-with-isindeterminate-while-trying-to-put-together-a-progressbar-xaml-tem)